# Pandas- Change default datetime to another time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe which has two `date` columns. I am doing difference of those two `date` columns to find number of days between them. The problem is the time in both of them starts from `06:00:00` so when the actual day gets over, the difference remains the same.

Here is the dataframe

```
ID            date1           comp     date2         daydiff
30       2021-01-01 23:00:00    1   2020-07-31 06:00:00 154
30       2021-01-02 00:00:00    1   2020-07-31 06:00:00 154
30       2021-01-02 01:00:00    1   2020-07-31 06:00:00 154
30       2021-01-02 02:00:00    1   2020-07-31 06:00:00 154
30       2021-01-02 03:00:00    1   2020-07-31 06:00:00 154
30       2021-01-02 04:00:00    1   2020-07-31 06:00:00 154
30       2021-01-02 05:00:00    1   2020-07-31 06:00:00 154
30       2021-01-02 06:00:00    1   2020-07-31 06:00:00 155
30       2021-01-02 07:00:00    1   2020-07-31 06:00:00 155
```

Here you can see when we have date as `2021-01-02` and time as `00:00:00`, there is no increment in `daydiff` (ideally it should have been incremented as date as increased by 1). It is only increasing when time is `06:00:00`.

I want the increment to happen when the date changes.

Comment: "*the time in both of them starts from 06:00:00*" - I'm having trouble understanding this in the example - _tel column seems to be hourly frequency while _maint column is just the same date/time repeated. Can you clarify? Do you want to change the time in _maint column to 00:00 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you right, you want to calculate the difference between dates and not between timestamps:

```
df['sincelastComp1'] = (df['datetime_tel'].apply(pd.Timestamp).dt.date -
                        df['datetime_maint'].apply(pd.Timestamp).dt.date).dt.days
```

**output:**

```
    machineID         datetime_tel  comp1       datetime_maint  sincelastComp1
0         30  2021-01-01 23:00:00      1  2020-07-31 06:00:00             154
1         30  2021-01-02 00:00:00      1  2020-07-31 06:00:00             155
2         30  2021-01-02 01:00:00      1  2020-07-31 06:00:00             155
3         30  2021-01-02 02:00:00      1  2020-07-31 06:00:00             155
4         30  2021-01-02 03:00:00      1  2020-07-31 06:00:00             155
5         30  2021-01-02 04:00:00      1  2020-07-31 06:00:00             155
6         30  2021-01-02 05:00:00      1  2020-07-31 06:00:00             155
7         30  2021-01-02 06:00:00      1  2020-07-31 06:00:00             155
8         30  2021-01-02 07:00:00      1  2020-07-31 06:00:00             155
```

Comment: note that you can set time to zero by "flooring" to the day, e.g. for a datetime series call `.dt.floor('d')`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you please upvote the question too :)